# Open multiple Json files with URL's and download the files contained in each using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automator

We will receive up to 10k JSON files in a separate directory that must be parsed and converted to separate .csv files.   Then the file at the URL in each must be downloaded to another directory.   I was planning on doing this in Automator on the Mac and calling a Python script for downloading the files.   I have the portion of the shell script done to convert to CSV but have no idea where to start with python to download the URLs.

Here's what I have so far for Automator:

```
    - Shell = /bin/bash
    - Pass input = as arguments
    - Code = as follows


#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/perl -CSDA -w <<'EOF' - "$@" > ~/Desktop/out_"$(date '+%F_%H%M%S')".csv
use strict;
use JSON::Syck;
$JSON::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;

# json node paths to extract
 my @paths = ('/upload_date', '/title', '/webpage_url');

for (@ARGV) {
    my $json;
    open(IN, "<", $_) or die "$!";
    {
        local $/; 
        $json = <IN>;
    }
    close IN;
    my $data = JSON::Syck::Load($json) or next;
    my @values = map { &json_node_at_path($data, $_) } @paths;
    {
        #   output CSV spec
        #   - field separator = SPACE
        #   - record separator = LF
        #   - every field is quoted
        local $, = qq( );
        local $\ = qq(\n);
        print map { s/"/""/og; q(").$_.q("); } @values;
    }
}

sub json_node_at_path ($$) {
    #   $ : (reference) json object
    #   $ : (string) node path
    # 
    #   E.g. Given node path = '/abc/0/def', it returns either
    #       $obj->{'abc'}->[0]->{'def'}   if $obj->{'abc'} is ARRAY; or
    #       $obj->{'abc'}->{'0'}->{'def'} if $obj->{'abc'} is HASH.
    my ($obj, $path) = @_;  
    my $r = $obj;
    for ( map { /(^.+$)/ } split /\//, $path ) {
        if ( /^[0-9]+$/ && ref($r) eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        $r = $r->[$_];
        }
        else {
             $r = $r->{$_};
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
EOF
```

Comment: You should look into using the [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module in python if you are wanting to download files from URLs

Comment: You received downvotes because A. You didn't attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and B. didn't produce a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and C. already has multiple [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+files+from+url+%5Bpython%5D) asking the same thing. This question demonstrates no attempt from yourself to solve the question and instead relying on others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Automator so perhaps someone else can address that but as far as the Python portion goes, it is fairly simple to download a file from a url. It would go something like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url) # assuming you don't need to do any authentication
with open("my_file_name", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Requests is a great library for handling http(s) and since the content attribute of the Response is a byte string we can open a file for writing bytes (the "wb") and write it directly. This works for executable payloads too so be sure you know what you are downloading. If you don't already have requests installed run `pip install requests` or the Mac equivalent.

If you were inclined to do your whole process in python I would suggest you look at the [json](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.33.0.windows.2/Git-2.33.0.2-64-bit.exe) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) packages. Both of these are part of the standard library and provide high-level interfaces for exactly what you are doing

**Edit:**
Here's an example if you were using the `json` module on a file like this:

```
[
  {
  "url": <some url>,
  "name": <the name of the file>
  }
]
```

Your Python code might look similar to this:

```
import requests
import json

with open("my_json_file.json", "r") as json_f:
    for item in json.load(json_f)
        r = requests.get(item["url"])
        with open(item["name"], "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Do I need to explicitly define the name of the JSON file in my code or can *.json work just fine?

Comment: for that you're going to want to look into [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). 
[os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) might be useful